# Data Tables not displaying when there are data in the <tr>

Tags: html, datatables

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#table_id').DataTable();
  } );  
</script>
```

Stylesheet and js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Table HTML:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>

</tbody></table>
```

This works fine, but when I try to add

```
<tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
</tr>
```

In between the

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

it doesn't show the search and pagination, and even the sorting anymore.

Comment: please show me your display class code of css

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery capitalization is very important.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#table_id').dataTable();
  } );  
</script>
```

dataTable is the correct capitalization according to the documentation

[jQuery dataTables documentation](http://www.datatables.net)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmzfsysy/)

Comment: If this is the answer for your question, make sure to mark it as the answer:-)

Answer (score 1):

Just also had this problem and I solved it by putting same amount of td and th.

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Row 1 Data 1</th>
                <th>Row 1 Data 2</th>
                <th>Row 1 Data 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Row 2 Data 1</th>
                <th>Row 2 Data 2</th>
                <th>Row 2 Data 3</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Should work properly. >.>